# Python: Write list of lists to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In my python script I'm having a list that has the following structure:

```
['00:00', 'abc', '2', 'xyz']
['00:01', 'cde', '3', 'sda']
```

and so on. I want to write this list to csv file in a way that every element is in separate row and every string in one element is in separate column. So I want to end up with the following result in csv file:

```
     A     |     B    |     C    |     D
1  00:00   |    abc   |     2    |    xyz     
2  00:01   |    xyz   |     3    |    sda
```

Currently I have a code like this:

```
with open('test1.csv',mode='w',encoding='UTF-8') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')
    for x in data:
        wr.writerow(x)
```

and the result I get is that every element of the list is written to column A, so it looks like this:

```
             A               |       
1  '00:00','abc','2','xyz'   |
```

How can I achieve splitting each string to separate column in csv file?

--edit

If I run the code from the first three answers I get the same result(except for the delimeter):

[image]

But my idea it to get 00:00 in column A, -6 in column B and so on..

Comment: Those are two lists. Can you confirm if its a list of lists or a dict of lists maybe?

Comment: Actually it's a 2 dimensional array/list. The whole structure is called data and I can get the value for each string by typing data[i][j]

Comment: Please share how `data` looks like?

Comment: Please provide code of an [mre].

Comment: Sorry, the it's the list of lists, so it has a structure: [['00:00', 'abc', '2', 'xyz']
['00:01', 'cde', '3', 'sda'] ]

Comment: Regarding your edit comment, these solutions are correct in that they create a delimited output. Now, it’s up to you to tell Excel (as that appears to be what you’re using) **how** to delimit the file. Only then will the values appear columnised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `pandas` approach?  Nice and simple ...

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['00:00', 'abc', '2', 'xyz'], ['00:01', 'cde', '3', 'sda']] 
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# Load data into a DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
# Write the CSV.
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) you can change the separator using the `sep` parameter.

#### [Edited] Output:

Content of `output.csv` as shown from the console:

```
user@host ~/Desktop/so
$ cat output.csv
A|B|C|D
00:00|abc|2|xyz
00:01|cde|3|sda
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesnt work.. Still all of the strings are written to one column

Comment: Just opened the CSV in Libre Calc and each value is in its own column as expected.  I'll revise the output because it is misleading.

Comment: @izotop - I've updated to use a pipe delimiter `|` for you.  Just pass whatever you like into the `sep` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

How each list appears in CSV file depends on what data structure `data` is.

For `data` to be a list of lists, following code should work fine.

```
import csv

data = []
d1 = ['00:00', 'abc', '2', 'xyz']
d2 = ['00:01', 'cde', '3', 'sda']

data.append(d1)
data.append(d2)

with open('results_file.csv', mode='w') as results_file:
    results_writer = csv.writer(results_file, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', 
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    results_writer.writerow(['A','B','C','D'])
    for x in data:
        results_writer.writerow(x)
```

results_file.csv looks like:

```
A|B|C|D
00:00|abc|2|xyz
00:01|cde|3|sda
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it if my data list has a lot of elements not only 2?

Comment: The code in answer should work for any number of list elements in `data`, not just for 2. I had added 2 lists in `data` just for an example.